# Stack run single benchmark

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, haskell-stack

I have multiple benchmarks defined in my cabal file:

```
benchmark my-gauge-bench
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:
      bench/gauge
  ghc-options: -Wall -Wcompat -Wincomplete-record-updates -Wincomplete-uni-patterns -Wredundant-constraints -Wall -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      QuickCheck
    , base >=4.10 && <10
    , bytestring
    , gauge
  default-language: Haskell2010

benchmark my-weigh-bench
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_pkg_core_gen
  hs-source-dirs:
      bench/weigh
  ghc-options: -Wall -Wcompat -Wincomplete-record-updates -Wincomplete-uni-patterns -Wredundant-constraints -Wall
  build-depends:
      QuickCheck
    , base >=4.10 && <10
    , bytestring
    , weigh
```

How can I run only single benchmark (like `my-guage-bench`) using Stack ?

Comment: Just curious, `base >=4.10 && <10`, does the `&& <10` really add anything here?

Comment: @SimonShine I think it is to avoid warnings from `cabal` before uploading a package to Hackage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This applies to all targets in `stack`, be it tests, benchmarks or executables.

There is a cool little command in stack that can help you list all available targets, without resorting to dig through `my-package.cabal` or `package.yaml` files. It is especially useful for multi-package projects and will work for all packages listed in `packages:` field in `stack.yaml`:

```
$ stack ide targets
my-package:lib
my-package:test:doctests
my-package:test:tests
my-package:bench:weight
my-package:bench:gauge
another-package:lib
another-package:exe:my-cool-executable
another-package:test:doctests
another-package:test:tests
another-package:bench:weight
another-package:bench:criterion
```

Now that we know the list we can invoke specific benchmarks

```
$ stack bench my-package:bench:gauge another-package:bench:criterion
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like this to just run a single benchmark:

```
stack bench package-name:my-guage-bench
```